# Generating functions, the product between two formal power series with different denominators

Tags: combinatorics, power-series, formal-power-series

I'm a bit lost in trying to take the product of a power series between two functions $f(x) = \frac{1}{(1-x)^k}$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}{(1-x^r)^k}$.

I know both can be expanded to,
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{(1-x)^k} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}x^n \\
\frac{1}{(1-x^r)^k} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}x^{rn}.
\end{align*}

This is where I get a bit lost. Since the exponents for $x$ are different, it seems like the Cauchy product is not applicable. Is there a further step I'm missing?

Comment: Thank you, edited the original post to reflect this.

Comment: I don’t know whether it helps, but it’s not hard to show that $$\frac1{1-x}\cdot\frac1{1-x^r}=\sum_{n\ge 0}\left(1+\left\lfloor\frac{n}r\right\rfloor\right)x^n\,,$$ so you’re interested in the $k$-th power of that series.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {\left( \matrix{
  n + k - 1 \cr 
  k - 1 \cr}  \right)x^{\,n} } \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,m} {\left( \matrix{
  m + k - 1 \cr 
  k - 1 \cr}  \right)x^{r\,m} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,m} {\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {\left( \matrix{
  n + k - 1 \cr 
  k - 1 \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  m + k - 1 \cr 
  k - 1 \cr}  \right)x^{r\,m + n} } }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,s} {\left( {\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,m\, \le \,\left\lfloor {s/r} \right\rfloor } {\left( \matrix{
  s - rm + k - 1 \cr 
  k - 1 \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  m + k - 1 \cr 
  k - 1 \cr}  \right)} } \right)x^s }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,s} {\left( {\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,m\,\left( { \le \,\left\lfloor {s/r} \right\rfloor } \right)} {\left( \matrix{
  s - rm + k - 1 \cr 
  s - rm \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  m + k - 1 \cr 
  m \cr}  \right)} } \right)x^s }  \cr} 
$$